# Why is wrap causing my input to lose blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 with the following snippet:

```js
function fixTextbox(element) {
  var span = "<span class='k-widget k-autocomplete k-header k-state-default'></span>";
  var wrap = $(element).wrap(span);
}

$(document).on("focus", ".k-textbox", function() {
  console.debug("focus");
  fixTextbox(this);
  $(this).parent().addClass("k-state-focused");
});

$(document).on("blur", ".k-textbox", function() {
  console.debug("blur");
  $(this).parent().removeClass("k-state-focused");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" />
```

The problem here is that when I execute the `.wrap`, it un-binds the blur event.

Is there a different way that I should be encapsulating the input in the span that wouldn't lose the events? Or should I be manually re-attaching the events after the wrap?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue. Handlers shouldn't be removed and anyway you are delegating event here

Comment: How does one lose blur ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5ebC/1/

Comment: I think the problem is wrapping the element is causing a reflow in the browser which is removing the focus from the input element

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Your jsfiddle seems to show the problem exactly.

Comment: @A. Wolff: I shouldn't say that it is un-binding the blur event.  It just isn't getting called, and my assumption was that it got un-bound.

Comment: @Scottie ya, i see strange behaviour in Arun jsFiddle too

Comment: @A.Wolff it is firing blur event as soon as the wrapping is done I assume

Comment: @ArunPJohny seems correct assumption

Comment: @Arun P Johny: I don't see that it's calling blur at all.  The left/right borders just keep growing.

Comment: @Scottie check console

Comment: look at the console.... it is logging both focus and blur

Comment: another problem is in every focus a new span is wrapped around??? you may want to wrap the span once and then add/remove the class after that

Comment: @Arun: I actually do have code that checks first to see if it's already wrapped.  I just didn't include it for brevity sake.

Comment: My console doesn't show blur at all.  I'm running FireFox 27.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5ebC/7/ - It is a very nasty hack... does not solve the original problem

Comment: Ok, I modified the jsfiddle.  The first blur doesn't seem to be firing, but after the first one, it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49263/discussion-between-scottie-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that, when you wrap the input element with another element it is forcing some kind of browser reflow of the render tree which is causing the input element to loose focus.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5ebC/1/) - see in chrome - in console you can see both focus and blur being logged

A possible solution is to wrap the span around before the focus event - on document ready or if the elements are created dynamically then during the element creation itself.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.k-textbox').wrap('<span class="k-widget k-autocomplete k-header k-state-default"></span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5ebC/10/)

Comment: Jquery wrap function uses a clone! too bad